# Getting a VARCHAR2 type column: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, occi

I have a column of type and size VARCHAR2<50> in my db table. I am using getBlob() method in my CPP code to get the value. I face exception as followed.

### Exception:

ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

@ line Blob blob = rset->getBlob(1);

### Code:

```
    if(rset->next())
            {
                Blob blob = rset->getBlob(1);
                if(blob.isNull())
                    cout << "Null Blob" << endl;
                else
                {
                    blob.open (OCCI_LOB_READONLY);
                    int blobLength=blob.length();
                    Stream *instream = blob.getStream (1,0);
                    char *buffer = new char[blobLength];
                    memset (buffer, NULL, blobLength);
                    instream->readBuffer (buffer, blobLength);
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                    cout << (int) buffer[i];
                    cout << endl;
                    delete (buffer);
                    blob.closeStream (instream);
                }
                blob.close ();      
    }
```

Please let me know your comments. Thanks.

PS: I have checked the forum and got the post with the same exception but could not find relevant to what I face.

Comment: I also checked StackOverflow and found 37 similar posts, did you check each and every one of them?

Comment: Yes, I checked each one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the query to use `utl_raw.cast_to_raw(col1)` instead of simply returning the column.

Although I wonder if you would be better off using plain old VARCHAR2 instead of trying to process it like a BLOB.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was not in need of BLOB actually. However, when I tried to get the VARCHAR2 as a string using getString() I was failing. I was able to see the value being fetched in the string when I debugged. But after the line (string strCost = rset->getString(1);) is executed, the application failed without any exception. Below is the code: 
if(rset->next()) 
{ 
dMax = rset->getNumber(1); 
dMin = rset->getNumber(2); 
string strCost = rset->getString(1); 
}

Comment: I don't know enough about OCCI to help with that.  I recommend you post that problem as a separate question.  It's better to solve the problem with a string than to try to fix a workaround with a BLOB.

Comment: @ Jon Heller, Thanks I will post as suggested.